# having some troubles with execv (bash c)

Tags: c, bash, execv

i want to write a program which executes the command passed in argument to a .c file, but i'm having incomprehensible errors coming from the declaration of an array of char pointers; my code is the following:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

 if(argc < 2)
 {
    printf("Incorrect number of arguments.\n");
    return -1;
 }

 char* args[1 + argc - 2]; // this is causing the problem
 char cmd[10];
 /*
 * some operations...
 */

 char* test[] = {"ps","-l","NULL"};
 execv("/bin/ps",test);

 return 0;
}
```

the arguments of execv should normally be cmd and args, but it didnt work, so i tried a simple command, didnt work either, i'm getting the following error:

```
error: unsupported option (BSD syntax)

Usage:
ps [options]

Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
 or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
```

however, if i put 1 as the size of the args array, the ps command is executed... i'm pretty confused, and i'd appreciate any kind of help

Comment: `"NULL"`, seriously?

Comment: `1 + argc - 2`.  So, an array of characters that is one smaller than the number of arguments to your program.

Comment: @T.Saba please see the MAJOR hint that "Kerrek SB" gave you... Does "NULL" look right...??? Should there be Quotes around it???

Comment: oh yeah indeed... don't know how i missed it...mindless mistake i made here,  thanks